# Is there metrics & keylines for Android Wear 2.0 apps?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, design-guidelines

I'm looking for design guidelines for Android Wear 2.0 apps that contain metrics and keylines: standard margins, paddings, font/icon/button sizes and etc. Basically [this](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html) but for watch apps.

In [official specification](https://www.google.com/design/spec-wear/android-wear/designing-for-watches.html) I can only find font sizes but nothing else. Have Google ever published this kind of stuff? Or maybe someone have reverse-engineered this from official Google apps?

Comment: When it comes to the design guidelines for Android, it's pretty much the same with any other devices, including wear. The Android Wear design guidelines focus on the fonts and colors since it should be pretty much the focus (because of the limited space). The standard padding and spacing, the same with Android phones, tend to change/adapt depending on the screensize. Anyways, to answer the question, the ***official*** specs you linked is pretty much it. If you ever find any others, it would probably be a suggested/advised guide based on their own exp.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to write this post as comment but there are lots of words.

In my expirience, this is hardly difficult to find suggestions about android.wear 20. Wearable devices are not so popular nowadays. So, the companies do not want to update guidelines, etc. Futhermore, 2.0 are not very popular. I really do not think that the major concepts have been changes exapt the link in the author post.

Obviously, I just would suggest https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html and https://developer.android.com/design/wear/index.html